# will schedule threads of the same process to different cores benefitial

Tags: multithreading, caching, linux-kernel, scheduling

Well, I'm currently working on Linux scheduler, and i wonder if there is a situation that threads run on different cores will accelerate process in Linux. i already heard that pin threads of the same process to different cores will make cache 'hot', thus it's beneficial. however, if not pinned, but try to dynamic binding threads to different cores, will it have any benefits or what's the pitfalls? Thanks!

Comment: If two threads are scheduled on the same core, then they can only execute one at a time, or at best within the confines of hyperthreading. Two threads on different cores are more likely to be executing concurrently. But as with most things, "it depends."

Comment: @Jim Mischel, thx for your reply. i agree with you. two threads run on the same core may benefits the cache hit, and run on different cores may executing concurrently. i also read few papers, and find some other usefull linkages [this](http://calab.kaist.ac.kr/~hjukim/asplos13.pdf) and [this](http://eurosys2011.cs.uni-salzburg.at/pdf/eurosys2011-sukwong.pdf), it shows in virtualized environment(KVM, vmware esx etc.), dispatching threads of the same vm to different cores will be helpfull to LHP(lock holder preemption), and it's also good for vcpu IPI, thus improve the performance. Thanks again.

Comment: @JimMischel, for the bad news, my experiments have shown that, when run on different cores, cache-misses increased. it's also understandable: too many **reduplicated data** in limited caches(core-level cache and llc), degrade effective data rate.